# Which process did I start?

Tags: c#

I want to get a handle to the main window of the process I just started by calling `Process.Start()`.

This is easy when the process is not already running as the result of `Process.Start()` is not null:

```
var process = Process.Start(fileName);
if (process != null) 
{
   var handle = process.MainWindowHandle;
}
```

However if the process is already running then the result is null. In this case is there any way (managed or otherwise) to tell where the request was routed and which process consumed the start request?

Comment: in other words you want to start a process which is not working on the background?

Comment: the result *of what* is null? `Process.Start`? and what is `fileName` here - an exe? or a document of some kind?

Comment: The result of process start is null. Yes `fileName` is a document in this case; specifically an Excel document. At the moment I'm just looking at the process main window name to see if it contains the file name; feels a bit dirty.

Answer (score 2):

For me, this seems like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377).

Before you start your own process, I would check if there already is a process running from the `fileName` you specified. If so, then use the handle of the process you found, otherwise start your own process.

If your `fileName` is an exe or bat or some other kind of executable, the method below should work. If it as a document or something like a document, I'm quite sure this method won't work without further adjustments.

Basically, the code would look like this (pseudo-code!):

```
//see below for method definition
List<Process> runningProcesses = ProcessUtil.GetProcessesForExecutable(fileName);

Process process;
if(runningProcesses.Count == 0)
{
    process = Process.Start(fileName);
} else
{
    process = runningProcesses[0];
    // maybe some more code to handle more than one running process
}

var handle = process.MainWindowHandle;
```

All that is left is the implementation of `ProcessUtil.GetProcessesForExecutable`.

There are three possibillities to get a process by name resp. by executable name, but two of them have major downsides:

1. [`Process.GetProcessesByName(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9(v=vs.110).aspx)
   Downside here is, that the process name may differ from the executable name. Thus you might not find a running process by giving this method a filename.
2. [`Process.GetProcesses()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9(v=vs.110).aspx) with either iterating over the whole array or some LINQ-select
   Is safe in terms of executable name vs. process name, but quite slow with 700-800ms per execution in my tests.

The last possibility is using P/Invoke. Why P/Invoke? Turns out it was the fastest one with 5-6ms per execution in my tests.
I implemented this once in a project using P/Invoke, being inspired by [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.createtoolhelp32snapshot):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Util
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Utility methods for processes
    /// </summary>
    public static class ProcessUtil
    {
        //Code is inspired by http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.createtoolhelp32snapshot

        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern IntPtr CreateToolhelp32Snapshot([In]UInt32 dwFlags, [In]UInt32 th32ProcessID);
        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern bool Process32First([In]IntPtr hSnapshot, ref PROCESSENTRY32 lppe);
        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern bool Process32Next([In]IntPtr hSnapshot, ref PROCESSENTRY32 lppe);
        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool CloseHandle([In] IntPtr hObject);

        //inner enum used only internally
        [Flags]
        private enum SnapshotFlags : uint
        {
            HeapList = 0x00000001,
            Process = 0x00000002,
            Thread = 0x00000004,
            Module = 0x00000008,
            Module32 = 0x00000010,
            Inherit = 0x80000000,
            All = 0x0000001F,
            NoHeaps = 0x40000000
        }
        //inner struct used only internally
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private struct PROCESSENTRY32
        {
            const int MAX_PATH = 260;
            internal UInt32 dwSize;
            internal UInt32 cntUsage;
            internal UInt32 th32ProcessID;
            internal IntPtr th32DefaultHeapID;
            internal UInt32 th32ModuleID;
            internal UInt32 cntThreads;
            internal UInt32 th32ParentProcessID;
            internal Int32 pcPriClassBase;
            internal UInt32 dwFlags;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = MAX_PATH)]
            internal string szExeFile;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a list with running processes for a given executable path.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="exec">full path to the executable</param>
        /// <returns>a list containing all processes currently run by the given executable</returns>
        public static List<Process> GetProcessesForExecutable(string exec)
        {            
            List<Process> toReturn = new List<Process>();
            IntPtr handleToSnapShot = IntPtr.Zero;
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(exec);

            if (!fi.Exists)
            {               
                return toReturn;
            }

            try
            {
                PROCESSENTRY32 procEntry = new PROCESSENTRY32();
                procEntry.dwSize = (UInt32)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(PROCESSENTRY32));
                handleToSnapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot((uint)SnapshotFlags.Process, 0);

                if (Process32First(handleToSnapShot, ref procEntry))
                {
                    do
                    {
                        if (fi.Name.Equals(procEntry.szExeFile))
                        {
                            Process p = Process.GetProcessById((int)procEntry.th32ProcessID);
                            if (p.MainModule.FileName.Equals(fi.FullName))
                                toReturn.Add(p);
                        }
                    } while (Process32Next(handleToSnapShot, ref procEntry));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //some error handling would be neccessary here
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseHandle(handleToSnapShot);
            }
            return toReturn;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to explicitly marshal the `BOOL` return values from the other function calls. (ie- `Process32First`, and `Process32Next`) Per [CA1414](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms182206.aspx).

Comment: @theB Good suggestion, thanks. I will do this in a few hours and edit my code.